# Transcendence detection from algebraic constructions

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

I have a simple image or intuition in my mind that I can't seem to shake off, so I thought I'd seek help here.

Suppose we don't know if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} - \mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic or transcendental, and we'd dearly like to find out.

Now, if $\alpha$ is transcendental, the algebraic theory over (theory of polynomial equations with coefficients in) the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ should be essentially a copy of the theory over $\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand if $\alpha$ is algebraic but not rational, the theory should be over some non-trivial finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Has this dichotomy been used in transcendence proofs (which I know nothing about, but I have a notion that they are quite analytic), or is this too simple-minded?

Another way to put it: suppose we take a system of polynomial equations $S$ over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ where $t$ is an indeterminate, and then specialize whichever constructions we make from $S$ to $t$ equal to various elements of $\mathbb{C}$. The properties/invariants of these specializations should in general be different depending on whether $t$ is rational/transcendental or algebraic-but-not-rational. Is the difference detectable in some clever choice of S and one of its invariants which takes one set of values when $t$ is rational/transcendental and another disjoint set if $t$ is algebraic-but-not-rational *and* which can be decided to be in one set or the other without knowing a priori if the value of $t$ is rational, algebraic or transcendental? Or perhaps there is a "connection" on a bundle on the base Spec $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ constructed from $S$ whose singularities occur precisely when $t$ is an algebraic number? Some such thing ... may be it is hopelessly naïve and unworkable, or just plain wrong.